How to get rid of odorous paint?
My landlord used a chemically smelling paint that is designed to cover cigarette smoke but no one smokes here. I am allergic to the paint he used and the smell is awful. It was the base coat. He also put a regular colored coat and then he tried to get rid of the smell with a sealant but it just made it worse. Help! What can I use to get rid of the awful smell?

If the landlord wants to cover up cigarette smell, it must be because of the previous tenants, not as a preventive measure against the possibility of  you smoking. By "base coat" do you mean primer? By "allergic", do you mean that you are sensitive to the smell -- that'd be different from actual allergy, and "latex" paint has no latex, BTW.

perhaps open more windows, or get a bigger fan

Thanks. It’s too hot to open windows. And yes I am actually allergic to the chemicals, not the smell.
